# multiple div hide and show during the sequence

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this code, I want the `div` to show and hide during the sequence. In this code first `div` appears when the sequence starts, after sequence reaches image no 5, the first `div` is hidden and the second `div` appears. Then after thesequence reaches no 7, `div` no 2 is hide and `div` no 3 appears and finally when the sequence reaches image no 15, `div` no 3 is hidden and div no 4 appears. Is this possible?

```js
onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
        frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        j++;
        if(j === 14) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            
        }
    },100); 
}
```

```css
#animation img {
    display: none;
}
#animation img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.d-none{
display:none
}
.d-block{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation"> 
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging02.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging03.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging04.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging05.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging06.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging07.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging08.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging09.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging10.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging11.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging12.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging13.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging14.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging15.png" />
</div>
<div class="d-block">
this div is aappear1
</div>
<div class="d-none">
this div is aappear2
</div>
<div class="d-none">
this div is aappear3
</div>
<div class="d-none">
this div is aappear4
</div>
```

Comment: simply test the variable j and make theme appear like you do with image

Comment: can you please attached your code in this snippet?so i can easily manage

Comment: Are you sure you want to load 15 images and send 15 HTTP requests for one animation? I think you should be better of using sprite for this animation

Comment: but i didn't know the sprite animation if you give me a code than i can manage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution , I did the show/hide divs based on the index of the current picture

```js
onload = function startAnimation() {
  var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
  var frameCount = frames.length;
  var i = 0,
    j = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
    j++;
    if (i == 4) {
      showdiv(2)
    }
    if (i == 6) {
      showdiv(3)
    }
    if (i == 14) {
      showdiv(4)
    }
    if (j === 14) {
      clearInterval(interval);

    }
  }, 100);
}

function showdiv(index) {
  var previous = index - 1;
  var current = index;
  document.getElementById("div" + previous.toString()).className = "d-none";
  document.getElementById("div" + current.toString()).className = "d-block";
}
```

```css
#animation img {
  display: none;
}

#animation img:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.d-none {
  display: none
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging02.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging03.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging04.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging05.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging06.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging07.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging08.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging09.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging10.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging11.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging12.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging13.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging14.png" />
  <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging15.png" />
</div>
<div id="div1" class="d-block">
  this div is aappear1
</div>
<div id="div2" class="d-none">
  this div is aappear2
</div>
<div id="div3" class="d-none">
  this div is aappear3
</div>
<div id="div4" class="d-none">
  this div is aappear4
</div>
```

Comment: can we stop this sequence at image number 8 and after that image sequence play when i am scrolling is this possible in this code?

Comment: You have to make a new question and explain what you want briefly

Comment: @pratik did you ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need JS to do this, the easiest way is through CSS, take a look:

```css
#list {
 margin: 2em auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 600px;
 list-style: none;
 height: 15em;
}

#list li {
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 background: #ccc;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in both;
}

#list li:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
#list li:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 2s;
}
#list li:nth-child(4) {
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
#list li:nth-child(5) {
 animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0);
 }
 to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li>A</li>
 <li>B</li>
 <li>C</li>
 <li>D</li>
 <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but i want previous div is hide at a time only one div is appear

Comment: it is only an example, it is obvious you can combine animation as you want, try play with timing and add keyframes

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, considering `j` is the counter of the loaded images, you just need to test if this number is `< 5` then display `#div1` and hide the rest, etc ...

Please consider that this is not the optimal solution, there is so many ways to enhance it. Happy coding :D

```js
onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;
    var i = 0, j = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if(j < 5 ){
          document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
        }else
          if(j < 7 && j >= 5){
             document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
          }else
             if(j >= 7 && j < 15){
               document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "none";
             }else
               if(j == 15){
                 document.getElementById("div4").style.display = "block";
                 document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
                 document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "none";
                 document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
                }

        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
        frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        j++;
        if(j > 15) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            j = 1;
        }
    },100); 
}
```

```css
#animation img {
    display: none;
}
#animation img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.d-none{
display:none
}
.d-block{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation"> 
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging01.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging02.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging03.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging04.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging05.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging06.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging07.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging08.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging09.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging10.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging11.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging12.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging13.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging14.png" />
    <img src="http://jumpingfishes.com/dancingpurpleunicorns/charging15.png" />
</div>
<div class="d-block" id="div1">
this div is aappear1
</div>
<div class="d-none" id="div2">
this div is aappear2
</div>
<div class="d-none" id="div3">
this div is aappear3
</div>
<div class="d-none" id="div4">
this div is aappear4
</div>
```